# Multi Contacts Picker in android

Tags: android

I am trying to implement multi contacts picker in my application using [this](https://github.com/broakenmedia/MultiContactPicker) library. It works fine using activity but not in fragment. After Selecting contacts through `MultiContactPicker.Builder`, it doesn't call `onActivityResult()` method. Does any one know how this library works in fragment or any source example?

Comment: post your code for calling in fragment

Answer (score 0):

Your fragment has a host activity and you must put onActivityResult() in it and call your onActivityResult of your fragment.
here is an example:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
   super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent); // don't forget this line
   Fragment fragment = (Fragment) 
   getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(childTag);
   if (fragment != null) {
       fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Buddy i got my answer....Your code helped me to get the link that how onActivityResult() will work. So I am adding the code which helped me. thank you once again.